# I am creating HTML files from text files. I would like to enclose ALL numbers 0-9, with definition tags

Tags: regex, tags, editplus

I am creating HTML files from text files (HTML bible). I would like to enclose ALL numbers `0-9`, with definition list tags `<DT>` & `<DD>`, so that the following:

```
1 In the beginning...(example)..
2 And God said...(example)..
15 Adam was....(example)..
26 Cain was...(example)..
38 Enoch was...(example)..
```

would look like:

```
<DT>1<DD> In the beginning...(example)..
<DT>2<DD> And God said...(example)..
<DT>15<DD> Adam was....(example)..
<DT>26<DD> Cain was...(example)..
<DT>38<DD> Enoch was...(example)..
```

Being that this is the bible, I have HUNDREDS of THOUSANDS of numbers (verses) to place in tags, so I really need this shortcut. I'm, using EditPlus and know nothing about these other "scripts" you guys use. (sorry- Im a nube...), So I need a RegEx (or Find/Replace: something easy: "Ctrl+H".)
I can 'open' and 'close' the DL /DL lists by hand after I get all the verse numbers between & tags.

(I wish I was as smart as you guys! :)

Comment: See, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks, for future postings and double check your spelling. You also should include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: search for (\d+) and replace with <DT>$1<DD> enclosed ALL letter "D"s in the tags. "Numbers" were not enclosed in tags...?

Comment: Chris85: I tried 0-9 (without brackets) before- EditPlus didn't recognize it; I just added the brackets [0-9] (as per your suggestion), and EP still does not find it.

Comment: Maybe EditPlus doesn't support all of regex. Maybe try Notepad++ or look for another text editor that supports the parts of regex you need to use.

Comment: search ([0-9]+) and replace with  <DT>\1<DD> works!!! WoW, Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to limit this to the beginning of a line...? There are a lot of numbers withing the verses as well. If not, I'll just do this one at a time, which is WAY faster than manually inserting every tag. THANKS!!!

Comment: @RonRay Please see answer below if that answers the question please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]` is a number, `+` is a quantifier meaning one or more of the preceding character/group, and `()` is a capture group which will capture what is inside. So you could use

```
([0-9]+)
```

to capture all numbers. The value will be in

```
\1
```

You can use a `^` to ensure you are at the start of the line.

```
^([0-9]+)
```

You can read more here about regex operations supported by EditPlus, http://editplus.info/wiki/Regular_expression_syntax.